# Extracting elements from CDATA

Tags: java, xml, cdata

I have this XML file:

```
<description>
  <![CDATA[
    <tag1 hello world/><br/> 
    <b>Current Conditions:</b>
  ]]>
</description>
```

I need to extract`tag1`, `br` and `b`. Here is my code:

```
NodeList nl = eElement.getElementsByTagName("description");

for (int j = 0; j < nl.getLength(); j++) {
    Node n = nl.item(j);
    Element e = (Element)n;
    String s = getElement(e));
}


public static String getElement(Element e) {
    NodeList list = e.getChildNodes();
    String data;

    for(int index = 0; index < list.getLength(); index++){
        if(list.item(index) instanceof CharacterData){
            CharacterData child = (CharacterData) list.item(index);
            data = child.getData();

            if(data != null && data.trim().length() > 0)
                return child.getData();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Output is:

```
<tag1 hello world/><br/> 
<b>Current Conditions:</b>
```

But I need to have a `String [] str` with following values:

```
 str[0] = "hello world";
 str[1] = ""; 
 str[3] = "Current Condition:";
```

Comment: Perhaps JAXB would be of interes to you. It lets you bind xml to standard Java classes. That way you wouldn't have to do any xml parsing of your own and it would be a lot quicker to adapt to changes in the xml schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the CDATA block is to preserve the content as un-parsed character data (which is what you are seeing).  Once you have the `String` you could parse that to access it's data.

Comment: So are you suggesting I should use `regex` to split the string?

Comment: @Sam - Since `<tag1 hello world/>` isn't valid XML you will need to use something like regex to extract information from the `String`.